# How to programmatically add queries to a firestore call

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am provided a dictionary of key, value pairs which I would like to work with as a set of whereFields on a firestore query. Given the syntax of how whereFields are added to a document, I don't see how this is possible.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

For example, I want to do something like this...

```
   var queries = ["key1": 0, "key2": 1]
   let db = Firestore.firestore()
   var ref = db. collection("myDocument")
   for (key, value) in queries {
      ref = ref.whereField(key, isEqualTo: value)
   }
   let snapshot = try? await ref.getDocuments()
```

But this doesn't compile saying the ref is a collection but the right hand side is a CollectionReference.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to cast the initial [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/CollectionReference) to its superclass [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query.html) and use that to build the final Query.

```
var ref: Query = db.collection("myDocument")
```

A CollectionReference is just a Query with no filters on it.

Comment: Awesome I will try that out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, with this solution the documents returned are not decodable using `document.data(as: Type.self)` sigh.  Any workaround to this?

Comment: If you have a new question, you should post it separately with the specific code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: Yes, I have done that here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70191265/why-does-firestore-codable-support-not-work-for-this-example?noredirect=1#comment124090057_70191265