# Why does Firestore codable support not work for this example

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In this first example, it compiles and works properly returning all Project documents.

```
public struct Project: Codable, Identifiable, Equatable {
        
    @DocumentID public var id : String? = UUID().uuidString
    public var name: String
    public var password: String

}
    public static func testQuery() async ->  [Project] {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = db.collection("Project")
        let snapshot = try? await ref.getDocuments()
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                return try? document.data(as: Project.self)
            }
        } else {
            return [Project]()
        }
    }
```

However if I change the ref to be declared as a Query, the documents no longer support codable.  How can I fix this as I need to use Query to dynamically build up the query based on parameters passed.

```
    public static func testQuery() async ->  [Project] {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref: Query = db.collection("Project")  // this line changed
        let snapshot = try? await ref.getDocuments()
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                return try? document.data(as: Project.self). // this no longer compiles
            }
        } else {
            return [Project]()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does the Query guy come from?  Project?  I have never heard of it.

Comment: Have you checked this [comprehensive guide](https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/)?

Comment: Yep, the issue is using Query.  The reason I need to declare the ref as Query is I need to programmatically at `.whereField` constructs based on an input rather than knowing them at compile time.  The query builds successfully and returns documents successfully, however, those documents, for whatever reason, are not decodable (seems like they should be). Maybe this is a bug in Firestore Swift support

Comment: What happens when you change `let ref: Query = db.collection("Project")` to `let ref: Query = db.collection("Project").whereField(addSomethingThatYouKnowWillReturnADocument)`? Does it work then?

Comment: same issue unfortunately

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you try  the same task without using the Swift 5.5. await? e.g. use the `ref.getDocuments {}` closure?

Comment: I did not, that would have been a good thing to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that if you cast the ref from Query to CollectionReference then you can use the built in encoding and decoding features.

```
public static func testQuery() async ->  [Project] {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref: Query = db.collection("Project")  // this line changed
        let ref2 = ref as! CollectionReference
        let snapshot = try? await ref2.getDocuments()
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            return snapshot.documents.compactMap { document in
                return try? document.data(as: Project.self). // this no longer compiles
            }
        } else {
            return [Project]()
        }
    }
```